# Xcode Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have always been use to having two storyboards in Xcode until now. There was always one for the iPhone and one for the iPad.  However I do not like having just one and I would rather have two.  Is there any way to make two separate storyboards in Xcode 6? Also I would like to make more than two if it is possible because I think that it would be handy having a separate one for all the different size iPhone screens. I'm not sure if it is possible but I hope it is to have more that one Storyboard in Xcode 6.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more appropriate to learn how to use the size classes that are, essentially, "different storyboard" where you can re-arrange everything to your will for every size.

Look for tutorials online, they should be pretty easy to find.

Now if you really want to have to separate storyboard, I'm pretty sure you can do it just like before, invoke a different one according to the `UIDevice` currently in use.

Comment: Yes, This will surely cater your need of multiple xibs into a single xib. The new feature in iOS 8 "Adaptive User Interfaces" takes care of it. Check out the link https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/ .